# How to loop through json array in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

below is the json array , from each object i need to print link and name.
can achieve this from shell script?
I have tried using jq , but i was able to fetch only one value.

```
values[
{
  "Links": "https://abc/tset",
  "Dates": 1540204743643,
  "name" : test1
}
{
  "Links": "https://abc/tset",
  "Dates": 1539256093799,
  "name" : test2
}
]
```

Comment: Can you paste an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Your example isn't proper JSON. Please edit the question and either make it proper JSON, or indicate that it's really that format. In the latter case, can you rely on the line breaks always looking like this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$ jq --raw-output '.values[] | [.Links,.name] | @tsv' <<< '{"values": [{"Links": "https://abc/tset", "Dates": 1540204743643, "name": "test1"}, {"Links": "https://abc/tset", "Dates": 1539256093799, "name": "test2"}]}'
https://abc/tset    test1
https://abc/tset    test2
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:
`grep -Eoe ' "Links":([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){1}' -Eoe ' "name" :([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){1}'`

it will find `link` and `name` and shows a word after them.